# Set permission while relaunchApp isn't working

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

I try to set permissions while I `relaunchApp` but I keep getting this notification alert.

I try to do it like this:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.relaunchApp({ delete: true, permissions: {notifications: 'YES'} });
  });
```

And I get this alert:
[image]

How can I bypass this system alert which failed my tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade your `applesimutils` installation using `brew tap wix/brew && brew upgrade applesimutils`. Detox doesn't currently have a way to check that you are running an up to date version, and so it may silently fail.

Comment: It seems that the newer version `0.7.0` isn't working either.

Comment: Is an issue opened on the repository, but I let the comment, so someone could get known in advance and avoid any other problems :D

Answer (score 0):

Figured you have to set it up on the init file instead of your test file.

Init file

```
beforeAll(async () => {
await detox.init(config, { launchApp: false });
await device.launchApp({ permissions: { notifications: "YES" } })
});
```

And then use await `device.reloadReactNative();` to sync your app and tests